# Proving equivalent half life of SMA vs EWMA

Tags: time-series

I have recently read in a paper that the 25 day SMA and 36 day EWMA are equivalent for comparison in tests due to their half lives. The half life of the 25 day SMA is obviously 12.5 days and I understand the basic form of the equation to calculate the EWMA. I have been struggling trying to back out the half life from this form of the equation though. Would anyone be able to put me out of my misery and show me how to do it?

Comment: This is impossible to answer without knowing what "36 day EWMA" means. An EWMA is specified by the decay parameter $\lambda$ in the equation $y_t = \lambda y_{t-1} + (1 - \lambda) x_t$ so we would need to know what value of $\lambda$ you think a 36 day EWMA corresponds to.

Comment: It is common to pick a number of periods $n$ and then choose either $\lambda = 1 - 2/(n + 1)$ (which makes the EWMA have equivalent variance to an $n$-day SMA) or to pick $\lambda = 2^{-1/n}$ (which gives the EWMA a half life of of $n$ days) but this specification is very much up to the user.

Comment: @ChrisTaylor this has actually solved it perfectly thank you. You use n = 36 to solve for lambda from your first equation then use lambda to solve for n in the second which produces the expected answer.